# How to tell if a process is running on a mobile device

Tags: mobile, process, native, pocketpc, evc

I have the handle of process 'A' on a Pocket PC 2003 device. I need to determine if that process is still running from process 'B'. Process 'B' is written in Embedded Visual C++ 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetExitCodeProcess will return STILL_ACTIVE if the process was running when the function was called.

Answer (score 0):

Process handles are waitable. They are signalled - will release any waiting thread - when the process exits. You can use them with WaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects, etc.